# Does ${\rm SL}(n, \mathbb{R})$ have complement in ${\rm GL}(n, \mathbb{R})$?

Tags: group-theory

Does the special linear group consisting of nxn matrices of determinant one have a complement in the general linear group of $n\times n$ invertible matrices? I know that ${\rm SL}(n, \mathbb{R})$ is a normal subgroup of ${\rm GL}(n, \mathbb{R})$, but otherwise I have no idea how to go about finding a complement/disproving that there is a complement.

Comment: Consider the diagonal matrices with all but first entry equal to $1$.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks!

Comment: Moreover: if $n$ is odd, the scalar matrices form a *normal* (central) complement, i.e. the center of the group is complement. If $n$ is even, this is not the case.